# How to draw string objects at an angle in Processing?

Tags: processing

The code below draws a spiral using objects from a string array.  Everything is fine, except that I would like the text objects to be drawn at a roughly 45 degree angle at each instance (based on the current x, y coordinates in the code below) rather than being drawn horizontally (when the text is horizontally drawn, it naturally overlaps with other text at concentrated points along the top & bottom of the curve).  I researched some methods, but I'm still very new to all of this, and potential solutions have all evaded me.

```
String example = "";

String[] wordSet = split(example, " ");

float x, y;
float angle = 0;
float radiusSpiralLine = 10;

size (800, 800);
translate(width/2, height/2);
background(#ffffff);
smooth();
fill(0);

for (int i = 0; i < wordSet.length; i++) {


  angle += .05;
  radiusSpiralLine += .5;

  x = cos(angle) * radiusSpiralLine;
  y = sin(angle) * radiusSpiralLine;

  textSize(9);
  text(wordSet[i], x, y);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is tutorial](http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-17/example-17-8/) to very similar problem. In basic you need to store projection matrix by pushMatrix() then translate and rotate according to position of letter on curve and then restore matrix by popMatrix(). I don't know how exactly do you want to rotate you text but just fold round your `text()` function like this maybe it will help you:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(x, y);
rotate(angle);
text(wordSet[i], 0, 0);
popMatrix();
```

Comment: When I incorporate your suggestion, it seems to just rotate the entire drawing rather than rotate the degree at which each individual objects is drawn along the curve

Answer (score 0):

First, you should start getting in the habit of wrapping code in the `setup()` and `draw()` functions. Since you're drawing a static image you don't need the `draw()` function, but I think it's good practice to have those two.

Now, what you are doing now is simply translating the words by a very small amount. Do the math:

```
x = cos(angle) * radiusSpiralLine; //cos(.05)*.5 = .499
y = sin(angle) * radiusSpiralLine; //sin(.05)*.5 = .024
```

That means they move less than a pixel, and they're not rotating at all.

What you need is your good ol' friend, the `rotate()` function.

Let's re-write code:

```
String example = "These are a bunch of words going around!";
String[] wordSet = split(example, " ");
float x, y;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size (800, 800);
  background(#ffffff);
  smooth();
  fill(0);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2); //Translate when you need to translate, not before
  for (int i = 0; i < wordSet.length; i++) {
    angle = PI/5; //Our good friends, radians
    textSize(20); //What is this, text for ants? Change to 20  
    rotate(angle);
    text(wordSet[i], 20, 0);
  }
  popMatrix();
}

void draw() {
}
```

First notice, the `setup()` and `draw()`. I like them there. It looks nicer, I think.

A couple of important things to note.
The effects of `rotate()` and `translate()` are on the canvas are cumulative. 
We could have had the same effect in different ways:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < wordSet.length; i++) {
    angle = PI/5;
    textSize(20);
    rotate(angle); //always rotating by PI/5 ON TOP of previous rotation
    text(wordSet[i], 20, 0);
  }
//Everything from now on will still be rotated, we don't want that!
```

Slightly better, but not there yet:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < wordSet.length; i++) {
    angle += PI/5; //constantly increasing the angle
    textSize(20); 
    pushMatrix(); //push a new canvas on top of everything
    rotate(angle); //rotate by angle (which increases every loop)
    text(wordSet[i], 20, 0);
    popMatrix(); //pop the rotated canvas out, go back to original canvas
  } //Things won't be rotated, but they'll still be translated, since translate() is outside of pushMatrix and popMatrix
```

Hope this helps.